free radius 3.0.20 radacct logging
I’m running freeradius 3.0.20 on A Redhat 8 server and I’m trying to determine how file masks are determined in /var/log/radius/radacct. By default radius drops logs into this directory by creating a directory under it for each radius client as it’s used, then for that host creates the logs under that directory.
So /var/log/radius/radacct/192.168.1.1 w/ perm 700
Then /var/log/radius/radacct/192.168.1.1/reply-detail.log w/ perm 644
I see where I can affect the 644 permissions, but I’d like to change the default directory permissions.
Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks..
Paul
